# Calling function and passing parameters to iframe from parent

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to call a function and pass a parameter to a iframe javascript function from the parent.

I have

```
document.getElementById('iframeD').contentWindow.detect(name);
```

in my parent javascript

in my iframe..if I have

```
function detect(name){

   console.log(name);
}
```

it will gives me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token name
```

However, if I only call the function without parameter

```
document.getElementById('iframeD').contentWindow.detect();
```

and make my iframe function

```
function detect(){

   console.log('I want to pass the pare');
}
```

it will works.

What can I do to solve this? Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`name` is a reserved keyword in JS, so you can't use it for variables/arguments. Just use a different name both for your argument and when you call `detect`. Your code looks otherwise fine.

Comment: `name` is not reserved. It is a default property of the window object, though, which also serves as the global context, and so any `name` variables (or elements with the id name) will end up shadowing this.

Comment: it turns out it's the name variable problem for some reasons, after I changed the variable name, it works.